# Yielding streams in generator functions

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator, q, es6-promise

I have recently started using `Q.spawn` function to run generators that yield promises. This works well in browsers where the support for streams is yet to land but in case of node we have streams. If you're using streams inside a generator function and would like to yield once writer stream is done then your code becomes not so clean.

```
Q.spawn(function* () {
  yield new Promise(resolve => {
    let fromStream = fs.createReadStream('x.txt');
    let toStream = fs.createWriteStream('y.txt');

    toStream.on('end', () => resolve());
    fromStream.pipe(toStream);
  });
});
```

It works but as soon as I start dealing with a lot streams the code becomes really ugly. Can this be made as simple as following snippet?.

```
someGeneratorFuncRunner(function* () {
    yield fs.createReadStream('x.txt')
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('y.txt'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put most of that code inside the `Promise` constructor:

```
Q.spawn(function* () {
  let fromStream = fs.createReadStream('x.txt');
  let toStream = fs.createWriteStream('y.txt');

  fromStream.pipe(toStream);
  yield new Promise(resolve => {
    toStream.on('end', resolve);
  });
});
```

And of course if you're waiting for lots of streams, it would make sense to factor out the promise constructor call into a helper function:

```
function endOf(stream) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    stream.on('end', resolve);
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what I really want to know is whether it is possible to yield a stream and the runner then implicitly converts the stream into a promise. The problem that I am facing is `someStream.pipe(outStream).on('end', => resolve())` doesn't seem to resolve the promise. I am new to nodejs streams.

Comment: I don't think Q is extensible in that regard like Bluebird is. You could extend the builtin `Stream.prototype` with a `then` method to make streams thenable, that should allow them to be `yield`ed, but I'm not sure whether that would be a good practice.